# Only select most recent record (calldatetime) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to only select the most recent calldatetime and display that in my results, can anyone help? I need the results to only show the latest updated record

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.phonenum ORDER BY h.calldatetime) as rn,
    h.HistoryID,
    l.ProjectID,
    h.ProjName,
    l.CompanyName,
    l.Phonenum,
    l.fname,
    l.lname,
    l.Address1,
    l.Address2,
    l.Address3,
    l.Town,
    l.Postcode,
    l.county,
    h.CallDateTime,
    cb.CBDatetime,
    l.apptdate,
    l.appttime,
    h.CRC,
    c.Description,
    a.Firstname + ' ' + a.Lastname AS AgentName,
    l.Notes
FROM
    History h inner join
    cmp_UtilityTrade l on h.PhoneNum = l.Phonenum left outer join
    CRC c on c.CRC = h.CRC left outer join
    Agent a on a.AgentID = h.AgentID left outer join
    CallBack cb on cb.DialID = h.DialID
WHERE
    h.calldatetime BETWEEN '2016-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-15 23:00:00'
ORDER BY
    l.Phonenum
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.phonenum ORDER BY h.calldatetime DESC) as rn`, and wrap into outer `select ... where rn=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have the `row_number() over` window function setup the way you need it. Assuming it's returning the correct value, you simply need to filter your results by that `rn` value.  Just place your existing query in a CTE, and filter the results like so:

```
with cte as (<your_query_without_order_by_phonenum>)
select *
  from cte
 where rn = 1
 order by phonenum
```

Also note that you probably want to move the `order by l.Phonenum` clause outside the CTE, and place it in the outer query.

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, you may also have to fix the `order by` clause inside the `row_number()` window function to `h.calldatetime DESC`.